# module stop work front-end page when i login to back-end page of prestashop after clear cache is work find

Tags: module, prestashop-1.6

I use titanshop1.5 prestashop theme i got some problem when i go to back-end of my website.
"**module stop work front-end page when login to back-end page of prestashop but after clear cache is work find**"

1.when login to back-end first time:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHmvn.png)

2.when clear cache already:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLhJp.jpg)

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but this is not on topic on Stack Overflow - it's about app support rather than programming. You may be better off going through Prestashop's own support channels

Comment: okay thanks for help us.